# Processing: Creating multiple ellipses with for loop

Tags: processing

I am new to processing and was wondering how would I create a for loop on the indicated line to create 2 more ellipses? I want to create these ellipses without interfering with the trajectory of the ellipses.

```
     int xv = 200;
     int yv = 20;
     int xsp = 2;
     int ysp = 2;

     void setup() {
     size(700, 500);

     }

     void draw() {
     background(250);

     int xcoord = xv; { // x position. 
      **how do i create 2 more ellipses with a for     
      loop?
     int ycoord = yv;

   if (xcoord > width || xcoord < 0) { // left, right 
   walls
   xsp = -xsp; // move other direction
   }
   if (yv > height || yv < 0) { // top, bottom walls
   ysp = -ysp; // move in other direction
   }
   ellipse(xcoord, yv, 20, 20);

   xv= xv + xsp; // moves the ellipses
   yv = yv + ysp;
   }
```

Comment: Well, this is a claim for OOP approach... But could be done just adding more and more vars just like the ones you have. Some thing like int xv1 / int xv2 and so on... boring... Or making arrays to hold all that, int[] xv = new int[3]... still a little boring, take a look in thisarticle:http://wiki.processing.org/w/From_several_variables_to_arrays and also http://wiki.processing.org/w/From_several_arrays_to_classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, i made you an array style sample :)

```
int howMany = 100;// 100?
//here you make empty arrays
float[] xv  = new float[howMany];
float[] yv  = new float[howMany];
float[] xsp = new float[howMany];
float[] ysp = new float[howMany];


     void setup() {
     size(700, 500);
      for (int i = 0; i < xv.length; i++){
      //they all have same length so... all at once
      // here you populate them...
      xv [i] = random(width);
      yv [i] = random(height);
      xsp[i] = random(-4,4);
      ysp[i] = random(-4,4);
      }
       fill(0,40);
     }

     void draw() {
     background(250);

     for (int i =0; i < xv.length; i++){

       if(xv[i] > width || xv[i] < 0){
         xsp[i] = -xsp[i];
       }

       if(yv[i] > height || yv[i] < 0){
         ysp[i] = -ysp[i];
       }


       ellipse(xv[i], yv[i], 20, 20);
       xv[i] = xv[i] + xsp[i]; 
       yv[i] = yv[i] + ysp[i];
     }

   }
```

And a class (objects) sample as well:

```
int howMany = 100;// 100?
//here you make a empty array of type Sample
//One array to rule them all :)
Sample[] samples  = new Sample[howMany];



void setup() {
  size(700, 500);
  for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
    // call the constructor to create each sample with random parameters
    samples[i] = new Sample(random(width), random(height), random(-4, 4), random(-4, 4));
  }
  fill(0,40);
}

void draw() {
  background(250);
  for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
    //call methods...
    samples[i].display();
    samples[i].update();
  }
}



class Sample {

  //class vars
  float xv, yv, xsp, ysp;

  // a constructor
  Sample(float _xv, float _yv, float _xsp, float _ysp) {
    xv  = _xv;
    yv  = _yv;
    xsp = _xsp;
    ysp = _ysp;
  }


  void update() {

    if (xv > width || xv < 0) {
      xsp = -xsp;
    }

    if (yv > height || yv < 0) {
      ysp = -ysp;
    }

    xv+=xsp; 
    yv+=ysp;
  }

  void display() {
    ellipse(xv, yv, 20, 20);
  }
}
```